# Not Getting an Illegal Argument Exception when Decoding a NONBase64 String in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, base64, decode, decoder

I used both javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder. But when i give nonBase 64 strings i get no exceptions with BASE64Decoder

so

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    decoder.decodeBuffer("Asdghäö'¨öä'");
}
```

This throws no exceptions

and this,

```
DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("ÖSaAA&&%¤");
```

Throws IndexOutOfBounds

but

```
   DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("ASDGW&&");
```

doesn't give anything at all where i expect an IllegalArgumentException as it stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html)

Does anyone encountered this before? and what do you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: I see what you mean, I get the same behavior.  If you were to look at the source for DatatypeConverter.java [like this](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/jaxme/jaxmeapi-src/0.5/jaxmeapi-src-0.5.distribution-zip!/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.java?format=ok), you would see it calls some provider's implementation of DatatypeConverter methods.  It is possible that the reference implementation does not deal with this Exception?

Comment: yeah it doesnt deal with it at all, and i really dont understand why to be honest... I ended up writing my own validation method for this.